# Sharing React Native Component as a "black box"

Tags: reactjs, react, react-native

I'm looking for a way to share a React Native component with 3rd parties without having to share the actual source code.

Something like a `.jar` in Java or a `.dll` for C#.

[image]

So assuming we have company A and company B, i (as company B) am looking for a way to provide a react native library to company A without being able to navigate through my source code.

Ideally I want others to be able to

```
import CustomComponent from '...myCustomComponent';
```

but not being able to look in the actual code.

Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: see [Why is "Is it possible to:" a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I understand it seems like a request for feasibility study by the community but it really isn't. Maybe it is not the right place to ask the question.
A yes or no answer from someone who had a similar problem in the past would be ok (so that i know i should/shouldn't waste any more time). A pointing direction would be even better for sure. Thanks anyway. Will keep looking for alternatives.

Comment: Can't bring myself to close this one, especially with the close reason the other community members have chosen.  This isn't a request for code-writing assistance; it is a question about deployment.

Comment: There is something called a "Web Assembly" that may allow what you desire.  The link here may be a start to answer your question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAssembly/Rust_to_wasm  Problem with Javascript is that it can be uglified, minified, and obfuscated--but not provided as a binary.

Comment: This is the spec: https://webassembly.org/

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. @BerinLoritsch I have looked into Web Assembly in the past but i've always considered it as a mean of performance boost for graphics due to higher required coding effort. Your approach looks promising (apart from currently being the only one proposed :-) ). I had a quick look into it and found an npm [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wasm) to bring Web Assembly in the desired platforms (ios, android).

Answer (score 0):

Following Berin Loritsch's commented suggestion, i looked into Web assembly as a solution.

So just putting my findings here for possible future reference.

#### Objective

Share react native components with third parties, while *hiding* as much code as possible.

#### Possible solutions (until now)

1. Minify, obfuscate and/or uglify js code altogether.

   - **pros**: easy to implement.
   - **cons**: doesn't actually hides any part of the code.
2. Utilize Web Assembly for parts of the business logic

   - **pros**:

     - it also proivdes a performance boost for cpu hungry operations.
     - the compiled `wasm` file is not that easy to decompile and follow the logic.
   - **cons**:

     - addition of extra complexity - i.e. more programming languages in the game.
     - requires a WebView to actually utilize Web Assembly.
3. Take advantage of the underlying C++ capabilities existing both for IOS and Android platforms and implement parts of the business logic there.

   - **pros**:

     - close to chip => higher performance.
     - compiled library => as secure/hiden as possible (i think).
   - **cons**: more difficult/time consumming to implement.
4. Move as much logic as possible in a backend system and provide an API.